# When to use different server for a static file in django

Tags: django

I am in a scenario where i have to resize existing images before displaying them on webpage. For that purpose is it wise to use different server for storing my images, as django server may take bandwidth to fetch images from another server.

Comment: Did you find [a solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is wise you use seperate server for static files. It is also mentioned in the django official documents.Check this  [serving static files from dedicated server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/deployment/#serving-static-files-from-a-dedicated-server)

Answer (score 1):

Absolutely. Especially for images, it is very meaningful to use infrastructures which were built for this purpose.

It is not without reason that [cloudinary](https://cloudinary.com/) is a dedicated cdn service for images that can be manipulated on the fly.

You might even consider [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/) as a great cdn solution for photos or slideshows.

By all means, outsourcing photo delivery will boost the performance along with the perceived quality of services that your webiste provides.